# Identical Sql Query gives different result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing problem with sql query I have two queries and I think they are Identical but they give different result (number of rows). Please can any

One query is: (in below query rows where status = 'absent' are not showing)

```
SELECT
EmpId,
convert(varchar(12),
Att_Date,101)as Date,
TimeIn1,
TimeOut1,
TimeIn2,
TimeOut2,
Shift,
Status,
Remark 
FROM 
Attendence2 WHERE EmpID='xyz' And (Att_Date BETWEEN '12/1/2013' AND '12/31/2013') AND BranchID='pqr'  ORDER BY Att_Date
```

Another Query is: (in below query I am getting the expected result i.e. all rows are appearing)

```
SELECT [EmpID]
  ,[Shift]
  ,convert(varchar(12),Att_Date,101)as Date
  ,[TimeIn1]
  ,[TimeOut1]
  ,[TimeIn2]
  ,[TimeOut2]
  ,[Status]
  ,[Remark]
 FROM [maw].[dbo].[Attendence2] where EmpID = 'xyz' and (Att_Date between '12/1/2013' and '12/31/2013') and BranchID = 'pqr' order by Att_Date
```

Comment: What does `SELECT DB_NAME()` return?

Comment: SELECT DB_NAME() returns master

I just found that when I am using [maw].[dbo].[Attendence2] instead of Attendence2 I get the proper result, can you please this?

Comment: Maybe there is a table "Attendence2" on the master database ? (which do not contains the same data)

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal remove the "[maw].[dbo]." from the second query as cubit ouch is getting at. At that point you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: thanks Sir I got this... there is a Attendence2 table in master database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be another table created in Master Database. Both the query looks the same but actually they are different.

In order to get rid of mistake what I do is :

```
`
 Use DatabaseName
 GO

 Select * From [SchemaName].[TableName]
`
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two tables named Attendence2 residing in different databases.

```
SELECT * FROM [maw].[dbo].[Attendence2]
SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[Attendence2]
```

These tables contain different data.